# Text before item

Tags: enumitem

Is there any way to put some text before the first item of a list, but to maintain the spaces (indents, margins) of the whole list?
[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

*SOS* \begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum*[4-6][7-12]
\item \lipsum*[4-6][7-12]
\item \lipsum*[4-6][7-12]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{enumerate}[labelsep=0ex,align=left,start=2]
\item[*SOS*~1.~] \lipsum*[4-6][7-12]
\item \lipsum*[4-6][7-12]
\item \lipsum*[4-6][7-12]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also play around with `leftmargin=4em` etc. to adjust the "indentation" of the list relative to the main body text if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{enumerate}[wide, before=\stepcounter{enumi}, leftmargin=*]
\item[\hspace*{-\parindent}*SOS* \theenumi.]\lipsum*[4-6][7-12]
\item \lipsum*[4-6][7-12]
\item \lipsum*[4-6][7-12]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `wide` doesnt seem to be the right tool for this. OP wants the paragraph lines to hang on the same level as the first line of each item (compare your image with theirs).

Comment: It works with wide, but I forgot to set the `leftmargin` key. Fixed. Thank you for pointing it!